# Express JS is receiving an empty req.body from ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am currently having a problem with React and Express JS form submit function. It seems like my nodeJS running on port 5000 is receiving an empty object from my ReactJS running on port 8080 using fetch method.

React : Contact.js

```
handleSubmit(e)
{    
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      contact: this.state.contact,
      email: this.state.email,
      message: this.state.message,
    }

    var url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/insertUsers';

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

NodeJS : server.js

```
const express     = require('express');
const { Client }  = require('pg');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const app         = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/insertUsers', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.write('you posted:\n') 
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
}); 

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 5000');
});
```

Comment: check your state of react app if it is empty

Comment: already did, but it's not empty, I also tried a hardcoded body and I am still receiving an empty object

Comment: change the order of bodyparser

Comment: just random guess , try res.send instead of res.end

Comment: Try from postman and check if there is any issue with server file

Comment: also tried postman and res.send but it always give me an empty object

Comment: both chrome network request and postman return {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  mode: 'no-cors'
}).then((result)=>{
   console.log("output" + result.json());
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**EDIT 2**

for backend, install `cors` and add the following lines before route.

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

**EDIT 3**
perform `npm install morgan` then copy these lines inside the code

```
var morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Comment: I'm still facing issues in sending form data to node. Need help here.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of `bodyparser` middleware like this.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: thank you for answering!  Unfortunately, it's still empty object

Comment: Inspect the network console and check the request body is proper or not

Comment: also try to change `res.send` to `res.json(req.body)`

Comment: As a default, I am always checking the Chrome's console network and it displays the request payload (object) correctly

Comment: What was the `content-type ` there ,share a screenshot of full payload here

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a request with the content-type of 'application/json' but express is expecting a content-type of 'text/json'. Usually, when req.body is empty content-type is the first suspect you should be looking at.

Comment: are you saying that I need to change the headers of my reactjs?

Comment: In your server.js change "res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')" to ''res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')"

Answer (score 1):

I am ashamed that I struggled with this for hours. I still haven't gotten it to work with file uploads.

But I did get it to work with a normal form by encoding JSON and sending that along with axios, instead of fetch

My js code

```
    var data = {
      id: this.state.id,
    }

    console.log('data',data)
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();

    bodyFormData.set('id', this.state.id);
 
    var url = ' http://localhost:3000/get-image-by-id';

console.log("bodyFormData: ", bodyFormData);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      // headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }


    })
      .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Form Code

````
      <form method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <label>
          Transaction ID
          <input
            type="text"
            name="id"
            value={this.state.id}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at your code close enough. My bad

```
app.post('/api/insertUsers', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.write('you posted:\n') 
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
});
```

Should be

```
app.post('/api/insertUsers', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.body)
});
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Can you throw in a console.log(req.body) before the res.json(req.body). It will log to your terminal that you are running Node from. Also, through in a console.log('Test') to make sure you are hitting the server and that the terminal is outputting console.logs

Comment: Yes, I tried it also, the ReactJS is hitting the Express, and the request payload is displaying on my console so I am assuming that REactJs sends the data properly

Answer (score 0):

try using axios instead of fetch 
I rewrote ur code like this and it works perfectly

server

```
const express     = require('express');
const { Client }  = require('pg');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const app         = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/insertUsers', function(req, res) {
// console.log(req);
console.log(req.body);
res.send(req.body);
}); 

app.listen(3001, () => {
 console.log('listening on port 3001');
});
```

react (ensure you have axios installed)

`handleSubmit(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
               name: "zadiki",
               contact: "0702002109",
               email: "zadiki",
               message: "test",
              }
       console.log("wow");
       var url = ' http://localhost:3001/api/insertUsers';
       axios.post(url,data)
        .then(response=>console.log(response))
        .catch(e=>console.log(e))
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I ended up getting mine working after I ran into the same problem.

I noticed your react code has "mode: 'no-cors'," that was causing problems with mine so I removed it.

-------- Below is my handle submit code for React ------------

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = "http://localhost:3001/register"
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }

    fetch(url, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

I used express.json instead of bodyParser. You also had a typo in your express code, it should say res.send instead of res.end

--------- Below is my Node Express Code  -----------

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

// Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(multer().array()); 

app.post('/register',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(200)
        .json({status:"Success", data:{body: req.body })
}); 

app.listen(3001, () => console.log(`Running on 3001`))
```

I was able to send form data using postman and react using the code above. Feel free to change it to accommodate your needs.