# The req.body is empty in node.js sent from react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, fetch

I create an app in react. I am trying to use fetch with a post to a different port of localhost. I received the req on the server, but my body is empty. Why my body is empty? I don't understand.

Code in React function:

```
export default function Sending() {
    async function handleSubmit(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          try{
              let result = await fetch('http://localhost:5000',{
                method: 'post',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'example@gmail.com' })
              })
    
              console.log(result)
          } catch (error){
            console.log(error)
          }
    }
 return (
    <>
      Have a Form here
    </>
  )
}
```

the console log of browser:

> ```
> Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
>   body: null 
>   bodyUsed: false 
>   headers: 
>   Headers {} 
>   ok: false
>   redirected: false 
>   status: 0 
>   statusText: "" 
>   type: "opaque" 
>   url: ""
>   __proto__: Response
> ```

my simple server hold on node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send("Hello")
})

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, Benny")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Can you post the `node.js` code as well?

Comment: yeah, definitely need your node  code as well. Please update your question with the node router function, so that we can see how it's implemented.

Comment: Sure, already updated

Comment: Is your front-end running on a different port?

Comment: @painotpi front-end running on localhost:3000

Comment: It may be a parsing issue. You can try to send body without parsing it! from `JSON.stringify({ email: 'example@gmail.com' })` to `{ email: 'example@gmail.com' }`. Just give it a try!

Comment: @AlessandroFoolishCiakDAnton I tried before. The server received the body of req which is {}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options: _“Note that mode: "no-cors" only allows a limited set of headers in the request: […]”_ - one of the restrictions is, that you are limited to the Content-Types `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. You are trying to set `Content-type: application/json` here, so I don’t think this is supposed to go through in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are trying to post JSON
2. To do that you need to set a `'Content-type': 'application/json'` request header
3. This is only allowed on a cross-origin request when you have permission from CORS (from a preflight request).
4. You said `mode: 'no-cors'`, a declaration that you do not have or want permission to do *anything* from CORS, so the browser will silently ignore anything that needs CORS permission
5. The request arrives at the server without `'Content-type': 'application/json'` so the body-parser doesn't know that it needs to decode the JSON

---

You need to:

- **Remove** `mode: 'no-cors'`
- Configure the server to support CORS **including for preflight requests**

This is most easily done with the [`cors` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
}

const configuredCors = cors(corsOptions);

app.options('*', configuredCors)

app.post('/', configuredCors, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send("Hello")
})
```

Comment: When I remove the `mode: 'no-cors'`, the browser of react would error which is `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: @SuerTe_H — Yes, you need to do both steps of the solution, not just the first one.

Comment: Yes, I also configure the server to support CORS. But the browser error that can't send to the server.

Comment: I fixed it with adding `app.use(cors())`

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing cors and add it to your code such as shown bellow

```js
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Then with the help of morgan

`const morgan = require('morgan');`

Consider reading a previous similar case as shown here
[Express JS is receiving an empty req.body from ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847159/express-js-is-receiving-an-empty-req-body-from-reactjs)

Comment: I tried the solution, it still empties from req body

Answer (score -1):

From the first glacne; you are sending over a string with the stringify. Node body-parser trys to parse the json. Try removing the stringify and just sending the object over.