# I get 'Error executing SQL query: Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL' when I add to a row to the db where the primary key is auto-incremented

Tags: reactjs, oracle, oracle21c

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE countries 
(
    country_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    country_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I am trying to send a post request to this to insert a row in my database. This is the body of my POST request {"country_name" = "PK"}
I'm getting this error when I send the post request

I am using Oracle 21c btw

> Error executing SQL query: Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("C##USER"."COUNTRIES"."COUNTRY_NAME")
> Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-01400/
>
> at Protocol._processMessage (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\node_modules\oracledb\lib\thin\protocol\protocol.js:172:17)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async ThinConnectionImpl._execute (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\node_modules\oracledb\lib\thin\connection.js:195:7)
> at async ThinConnectionImpl.execute (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\node_modules\oracledb\lib\thin\connection.js:927:14)
> at async Connection.execute (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\node_modules\oracledb\lib\connection.js:861:16)
> at async Connection. (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:165:14)
> at async AddNewCountry (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ticketeer\backend\controller\countriesController.js:126:13) {
> offset: 46,
> errorNum: 1400,
> code: 'ORA-01400'
> }

In my countries controller, I tried hard-coding req.body.country_name and assigning it a country name as a string. When I sent the request, that country name got entered in the database but the country_id that should've been 2 was 22. Here is my API code for AddNewCountry

```
AddNewCountry: async function (req, res){
        let connection ;
        try {
 
          connection = await getConnection();
            const query = `INSERT INTO countries (country_name) VALUES (:1)`;
            const binds = [req.body.country_name];
            const options = {
              autoCommit: true, 
            };
            
            await connection.execute(query,binds,options);
            res.status(202).send("Added");
        } 
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error executing SQL query:', error);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
          
        } 
        finally {
            if (connection) {
              try {
                // Release the connection when done
                await connection.close();
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error closing database connection:', error);
              }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: If the database is showing that `country_name` is getting to the insert command as null it only means that the bindings operation is not working. I'm no expert on reactjs so I would recommend checking the binding part of this construct.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting the value of `req.body.country_name` to ensure it has a value before binding?

Comment: @PaulW yes I did. It's null but I don't know why. This is my post request's body {
  "country_name": "USA"
}

Comment: "the country_id that should've been 2 was 22" - identity columns are based on sequences, which are not gapless, so this isn't unexpected (even if it isn't what you want), esp. with RAC. Your actual issue is nothing to do with Oracle though, you need to figure out why your body is empty, I guess. (Maybe [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64964363/266304)? Just a guess...)

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for pointing that out. still can't fix it though. I've tried most things

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was an issue with how I was executing my POST request on Postman. Postman uses a default Text setting in the body of the POST requests instead of JSON, which made my req.body undefined.
Changing it to JSON fixed the issue.